# Comment on the same line as \If in algorithm introduces a vertical whitespace

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, comments

I am using the `algorithm2e` package to write a pseudo code algorithm. I would like to add a comment with `\tcp`, on the same line as an `\If` statement. I managed to do so by putting the `\tcp` command between parenthesis right after the `\If`, but it introduces a vertical space between the If and the following line.

```
\usepackage[titlenumbered,ruled,noend,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[t]
        \If(\tcp*[l]{comment}){$k = K$}{do stuff}
        \If{$k \neq K$}{do other stuff}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use the `[h]` specification of `\tcp*`, as explained [here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) at page 32.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titlenumbered,ruled,noend,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[t]
        \If(\tcp*[h]{comment}){$k = K$}{do stuff}
        \If{$k \neq K$}{do other stuff}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As an addendum: if you wish your comment to show up at the right edge of the algorithm, rather than right next to the text, use [f] instead (as also explained on the same page)